# Cannot style a div with CSS

Tags: html, css

I cannot figure out why my div's style is not applied. It must be something really simple and obvious, but not to me, not today.

This is a really simple login page.

HTML:

```
<div id="form_wrap">
    <div id="logo">
        <a href="#" title="#" id="logg"> 
            <img src="./images/smaple.png" alt="sample" />
        </a>    
    </div>

    <form name="login-form" class="login-form" action="#" method="post">            
        <div class="form_content">
            <input name="username" type="text" class="input username" placeholder="Benutzername" /> 
            <input name="password" type="password" class="input password" placeholder="Passwort"  />        
            <input name="submit" type="submit" class="button" value="Anmelden"/> 
        </div>  
    </form>     
</div>

<div id="langchoice">
    <span id="triangle"></span>

    <select id ="langlist">
        <option value= "1">Deutsch</option>
        <option value = "2">Englisch</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And the CSS (some minor background gradient changes to avoid code spaghetti here):

```
 *{
margin:0;
padding:0;
border: none;
outline: none;

  }



 /* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
 * { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }





   html{

background:#193358 url('images/bckg.jpg') repeat;

/* Ensure the html element always takes up the full height of the browser window */
min-height:100%;
height: 100%;
}



   body{
/* Workaround for some mobile browsers */

height: 100%;
min-height:100%;  
    background: #333;


   }


    a, a:visited {
outline:none;
color:#1c4f64;
    }

    a:hover{
text-decoration:none;
    }

    section, footer, header{
display: block;
    }



    #logo {

    text-align: center;
    }





    #form_wrap {
/* Center wrapper perfectly */
width: 440px;
height:400px;
margin: 275px auto;
z-index:2;
clear:both;
    }


   header{

   background: #333;
   background-repeat: repeat-x;
   width: 100%;
   height:300px;
color: white;
z-index: -1;
position:fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
    }



    .login-form {
width: 435px;
height: 320px;
margin: 20px auto 0;
padding: 50px 110px 60px;
position: relative;

background: #f2f3e7;
border: 0.5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
border-radius: 12px;



box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) inset;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6) inset;
     }



    /* Input field */
    .login-form .form_content .input {
width: 188px;
padding: 12px 25px 8px;
font-family: 'superficial_book';
font-weight: 400;
font-size: 14px;
color: #9d9e9e;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(256,256,256,1.0);

background: #dfdfde;
border: 1px solid #fff;
border-radius: 10px;

box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.50);
    }

    /* Second input field */
    .login-form .form_content .password, .login-form .form_content {
margin-top: 25px;
    }

    .login-form .form_content .input:hover {
background: #d3e3e4;
color: #416e75;
    }

    .login-form .form_content .input:focus {
background: #d3e3e4;
color: #416e75;

box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    }



    /* Animation */
    .input, .button, .langchoice {
transition: all 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }



    /* Login button */
    .login-form .button {

    position: relative;
padding: 8px 60px;
margin: 25px auto;
font-family: 'superficialbold';
font-weight: 300;
font-size: 14px;
color: #e3e3d5;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
text-shadow:1px -1.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 0px rgba(57, 128, 148, 0.5), 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
text-decoration: none;
background:#156785 url('images/button_bckg.gif') repeat-x ;
border-radius: 10px;
cursor: pointer;
box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #fff inset, 0 2px 0 0 #156785, 0 5px 3px #999;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px #fff inset, 0 2px 0 0 #156785, 0 5px 3px #999;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #333, 0px 2px 0px 0px #156785, 0px 5px 3px #999;
     }

    .login-form .button:hover, .login-form .button:focus,.login-form .button:active {
border: 1px solid rgba(256,256,256,0.3);
box-shadow:  0 1px 0 #333 inset,0 1px 0 #333;
-moz-box-shadow:  inset 0px 1px 0px #333;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #333;
color: #f6f4e7;
padding: 7px 60px;
position: relative;
top:-1px;
text-shadow:1px -1.5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0 0px rgba(57, 128, 148, 0.5), 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    }

    div#langchoice {

    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 200px;
    width:140px;
    height:34px;
    background-color:#F1BD4B;
    margin-left: -8px;
    padding:2px 10px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px 8px 8px 1px;
    border-radius: 1px 8px 8px 1px;
border:0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px 0px rgba(23, 34, 23;)
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px 0px rgba(23, 34, 23;)

    z-index: 10;

    }
```

Friddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/yp5yw/

Comment: @user1164654 Where are you linking to your CSS file?

Comment: Which div? What isn't being applied?

Comment: Created  friddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yp5yw/  AND as @JezenThomas asked, witch div ain't applied?

Comment: Which of the divs, and which styles are you referring to?

Comment: ya not getting your question ..where is the problem ?

Comment: Awww! Sorry, everyone! I forgot to say that the div#langchoice is not working. I have made a jsbin example: [link](http://jsbin.com/onubur/2/edit) and have put borders around divs, so #lanchoice also has a border but any other styling is not rendered. Thanks!

Comment: @Pēteris OMG! WHY is it working there and not on jsbin? What did I do wrong ( never mind the positioning , of course it need to be somewhere else )  ?! *puzzled*

Comment: @user1164654 in you jsbin it looks like you have langchoice set as a class in the html and are referencing it as an id in your CSS.

Comment: I found both `.langchoice` and `#langchoice` in your CSS, but your HTML above only has one `div id='langchoice'`, and your HTML in jsbin only has one `div class='langchoice'`.

Comment: @ScottBartell and Passerby Thank you! I've edited that now, but still it is not styled on jsbin.   http://jsbin.com/onubur/7/edit

Answer (score 3):

ERRORS IN

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px 0px rgba(23, 34, 23;)
box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px 0px rgba(23, 34, 23;)
                                           ^ the semicolon AND the alpha value.
```

CORRECT:

```
div#langchoice {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 200px;
    width:140px;
    height:34px;
    background-color: #F1BD4B;
    margin-left: -8px;
    padding:2px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1px 8px 8px 1px;
    border-radius: 1px 8px 8px 1px;
    border:0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px 0px rgba(23, 34, 23, 1);
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px 0px rgba(23, 34, 23, 1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px 0px rgba(23, 34, 23, 1);
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: I've edited that as well, but it is still not styled on jsbin. I'll try and copypaste the code from jsfiddle...

Comment: check here http://jsfiddle.net/3FxVu/ and can you tell us which browser and version you are using?

Comment: Oh, thanks everyone! Now , for me this is amazing: I've copied the CSS from jsfiddle that works(?) , and pasted it into jsbin, and it is NOt working there: http://jsbin.com/onubur/7/edit , and the same goes for my FF 15.0.1

Comment: here it is: http://jsbin.com/oboruv/1/edit are we gonna debug everything for you now? don't paste anything but body contents in the HTML panel :-P

Comment: Hahah! @Gustonez, thanks so much !! I am new to all this online tools and webdev, sorry! Hm, that means for me, that some other script is involved, i'll try and comment out one by one and find out. Thank you sooo much everyone! You rock!

Comment: since you are new here, please consider accepting this answer if it has fixed your problem. thanks

Comment: How do i do that? I click on the "answer has been helpful"?

Answer (score -2):

CSS3 styles are does not support lower version browsers. Please refer the link http://caniuse.com/

Comment: Your code works great for me. I am not sure why it didn't to you. I believe this might be the version of the browser you are using. please 
check the link http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing for CSS compatible versions.

Comment: That would mean that CSS3 is working on one div but not working on the other.